# Java JDK installer won't run

Tags: java, windows, installation

I tried the other solutions but they didn't worked, so please don't just say "It's a duplicated so now you have to open this link." Because I tried them.
I have Windows 8.1 and I installed Java 8 JDK some days ago, now I unistalled it because I've had some problems with it (like the PATH for cmd was not set), and after unistalling it I tried to open the Java installer, after the UAC popup nothing happen. I tried opening the installer "sandboxed" with the program "Sandboxie", the Installer opened 2 services, after a few seconds another service opened and then every service closed.
I have no error, no logs, nothing.
P.S.
I tried downloading again the installer 3 times, nothing changed.

Edit:
JRE Installer doesn't start either.
Edit:
I'm actually in safe mode with internet connection and the installer still don't want to run... I don't know what to do now...
I tried with "sfc /scannow" and it said there was no problem, I tried "DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth" too, no problem got reported.

Edit:
I tried running the installer with a Guest account, nothing changed. Anyway I found a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I searched for everything that contains "Java" in C:\ and I found some value (that could have prevented Java Installer from running because it thought Java was already installed), I deleted them (carefully, don't just delete everything on your computer, that's not the way.)
Now I tried launching the installer and.. Here we go! Finally I can install it.
Thanks to anyone who tried to help me, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You should add java in Path:

- Open the System Properties.
- Find the Advanced Tab in the Properties Window. Click Environmental Variables.
- Scroll down in the System variables and find the PATH variable.
- Select the PATH variable and click the Edit button.
- Add the Java installation path to the PATH variable (dir_java/bin)

And also create system variable JAVA_HOME

Comment: That's not the problem rn, Java doesn't even install.

Answer (score 1):

In my case problem was in C:/Users folder. Initially my OS language was not English, after changing, it causes some errors. I couldn't install jdk, couldn't run some desktop tools. After looking for the solution, I could found it. My user name in Users folder had non English letters. So, I changed name of user and it solved my problem:
https://superuser.com/questions/890812/how-to-rename-the-user-folder-in-windows-10

Comment: I Created another user and installed it from that user

Answer (score 0):

What antivirus are you using?

If your av has some kind of process viewer that you can use to see when it starts and when it terminates and if it is marked a suspicious. Here is a screenshot from my av. I use comodo [image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VF9iA.jpg)

If your av doesn't have this feature, try turning it off during the installation. Remember to turn it back on after you're done

Comment: I use Windows Defender, I don't really need an antivirus, anyway nothing changed, and Windows Defender can not be the problem because the installer started before...

Comment: Did you try running the installer as administrator?

Comment: Yes I tried. And when I run the installer it runs automatically as administrator, it asks for Administrator Permissions.